# I want to make bracket checker in python that counts the wrong brackets

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to program bracket checker program. But I want it to count the unmatched brackets. I am using python. And how can I use stack in this problem?

I have tried some code but it didn't work because it can't count wrong brackets.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # text = sys.stdin.read()
    text = str(input())
    stackie = []
    num = 0
    opening_brackets_stack = []
    for i, next in enumerate(text):
        if next == '(' or next == '[' or next == '{':
            # Process opening bracket, write your code here
            stackie.append(next)
            pass

        if next == ')' or next == ']' or next == '}':
            # Process closing bracket, write your code here
            if next == ")" :
                if '(' in stackie :
                    stackie.remove("(")
                else:
                    num += 1
            if next == "]" :
                if '[' in stackie :
                    stackie.remove("[")
                else:
                    num += 1
            if next == "}" :
                if '{' in stackie :
                    stackie.remove("{")
                else:
                    num += 1
            pass
```

Comment: Can you not just count the total number of each bracket in the code and do simple subtraction? `total_open_square - total_close_square`

Answer (score 0):

I have attached the following solution, hopefully it is self describing and will do what you want.

```py
def check_closed_brackets(open_bracket, nonclosed_opening_brackets, nonopened_closing_brackets):
    if len(nonclosed_opening_brackets) == 0: # There are no opened brackets remaining so the close must be invalid
        nonopened_closing_brackets.append(element)
    else: # Open brackets exist lets check them
        if element == ")" :
            if nonclosed_opening_brackets[len(nonclosed_opening_brackets) -1] == '(':
                nonclosed_opening_brackets.remove("(")
            else:
                nonopened_closing_brackets.append(element)

        if element == "]" :
            if nonclosed_opening_brackets[len(nonclosed_opening_brackets) -1] == '[':
                nonclosed_opening_brackets.remove("[")
            else:
                nonopened_closing_brackets.append(element)

        if element == "}" :
            if nonclosed_opening_brackets[len(nonclosed_opening_brackets) -1] == '{':
                nonclosed_opening_brackets.remove("{")
            else:
                nonopened_closing_brackets.append(element)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # text = sys.stdin.read()
    text = str(input())
    nonclosed_opening_brackets = []
    nonopened_closing_brackets = []
    for i, element in enumerate(text):
        if element == '(' or element == '[' or element == '{':
            nonclosed_opening_brackets.append(element)

        if element == ')' or element == ']' or element == '}':
            check_closed_brackets(element, nonclosed_opening_brackets, nonopened_closing_brackets)

    print('Number of Opened Brackets that are not closed: {0}'.format(len(nonclosed_opening_brackets)))
    print('Number of Closed Brackets that are not opened: {0}'.format(len(nonopened_closing_brackets)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to write a [classical bracket parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Well-formed_parentheses), an error in your logic was calling `remove` on the stack instead of comparing to the `pop`.

It's not that easy to be certain when it's working as expected and when it isn't, so a couple of test cases and their expected behavior go a long way, say, what do you expect to get as output for `'(asd(gdgd)[dfdf])'`, `'[(asd(gdgd)[dfdf])'`, and `'(asd(gdg{d)[df}df])'`?

Take this code for example:

```py
BRACKET_MATCHES = {')': '(', ']': '[', '}': '{'}

def bracket_check(text):
    stack = []
    for n, char in enumerate(text):
        if char in '([{':
            stack.append((char, n))
        if char in ')]}':
            match = stack.pop()
            if match[0] != BRACKET_MATCHES[char]:
                print(f"Can't match bracket '{char}' at {n}, "
                      f"conflicting with '{match[0]}' at {match[1]}.")
                return False
    if len(stack) != 0:
        print(f"Open brackets remaining at positions: "
              f"{' '.join(map(str, stack))}")
        return False
    return True
```

Given the samples from before, this is what we get:

```py
>>> bracket_check('(asd(gdgd)[dfdf])')
True
>>> bracket_check('(asd(gdg{d)[df}df])')
"Can't match bracket ')' at 10, conflicting with '{' at 8."
False
>>> bracket_check('[(asd(gdgd)[dfdf])')
"Open brackets remaining at positions: ('[', 0)"
False
```

This solution stops at the first unmatched bracket, mainly because that problem is *a lot* easier to solve than finding all unmatched brackets in a way a human would. The latter is computationally quite complex in a regular sized text, and is still not certain to give you the result you want.

Unless it is absolutely non-viable, working iteratively by fixing bracket errors as they come up is in my opinion preferable.